# Brownian Motion with drift (stupid question)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

How do you prove that 
$$ \lim_{t\to +\infty} (B_t+ct)=+\infty $$
almost surely?

$(B_t)_t$ is the standard *Brownian Motion* starting from $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible ways to prove it, depending on what you already know.  If you know the strong law of large numbers for Brownian motion, which says that as $t \to \infty$, $\frac{B_t}{t} \to 0$ almost surely, then we have
$$\frac{B_t + ct}{t} = \frac{B_t}{t} + c \to c\quad \text{a.s.}$$
Since $c > 0$ it follows that ${B_t + ct} \to +\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Is it possible to see the first result ($\frac{B_t}{t}\to 0$) as a consequence of the fact that the process $X_t:=tB_{1/t}$ is a BM too?

Comment: @avati91: Yes.  But in order to prove that $X_t$ is a Brownian motion (started at 0!) you probably had to first prove the strong law of large numbers, so watch for circularity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Would it be possible to use a Chung Fuchs type argument by discretizing B?

Comment: @badatmath: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: If we have for example a compound poisson process with drift, we check the probability that $S_t-ct\geq u$ for some positive $u$  for some $t$ which is the same as that for $\sum^n X_i-cT_i \geq u$ for some $n$ then use Chung Fuchs theorem on the steps of the resultant random walk. Im thinking if a similar argument can be made using Donskers construction of BM

Comment: Since BM is the weak limit of random walks