# Probability of finite hitting time for Brownian motion with drift

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, stochastic-processes

Let ( $B_t$ ) be a real Brownian motion with $ B_{0}=0 $. For $ c \leq 0 $ and $a>0$,  consider the stopping time $$U_{a}:=\inf \left\{t \geq 0: B_{t}+c t=a\right\}.$$ Le Gall claims we can compute $$P\left(U_{a}<\infty\right)={e}^{2 c a} $$

using the optional stopping theorem applied to the continuous martingale $$ \exp \left(-2 c\left(B_{t}+c t\right)\right).$$
How does this work?  If $\exp \left(-2 c\left(B_{t}+c t\right)\right)$ were uniformly integrable, we would have $$1=E[ \exp \left(-2 c\left(B_{0}+c 0\right)\right)]=E[ \exp \left(-2 c\left(B_{U_a}+c U_a\right)\right)]=E[e^{-2ca}\cdot 1_{U_{a}<\infty}]+E[0\cdot 1_{U_{a}=\infty}]=e^{-2ca}\cdot P({U_{a}<\infty}).$$ But $\exp \left(-2 c\left(B_{t}+c t\right)\right)$ is not  uniformly integrable.

So naturally one looks at $$1=E[ \exp \left(-2 c\left(B_{U_a\wedge t}+c (U_a\wedge t)\right)\right)]=E[e^{-2ca}\cdot 1_{U_{a}\leq t}]+E[\exp \left(-2 c\left(B_{t}+c t\right)\right)\cdot 1_{t<U_{a}}].$$
But how to show that the second term goes to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c<0$. The term $E[e^{-2c(B_t+ct)}\mathbf{1}_{\{U_a>t\}}]$ converges to zero as $t \to \infty$. To see this, write $c=-b$ for $b>0$. Then note that if $U_a>t$ then $B_t-bt<a$ and so $e^{2b(B_t-bt)}<e^{2ba}$, therefore $0\leq e^{2b(B_t-bt)}\mathbf{1}_{\{U_a>t\}}<e^{2ba}$. Now [note](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806722/brownian-motion-with-drift-stupid-question) that $B_t-bt\to -\infty$ a.s.; it follows that $e^{2b(B_t-bt)}\to 0$ a.s. and so $e^{2b(B_t-bt)}\mathbf{1}_{\{U_a>t\}}\to 0$ by (a.s.) squeeze. You can conclude by dominated convergence.

Comment: omg i missed that it’s dominated. head slap